# CSS: How to stop a line break between someone's first and last name?

Tags: css, line-breaks

Here's a [screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/435ak.png). "Eli Freedman" is split over two lines. Is there a way where first and last names, if there's a line break between them, can automatically go together to the second line? In this case, "Eli Freedman" would not split and would automatically move to the second line underneath "Note/Volume 111/April 2023." Thanks!

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:
word-wrap: break-word !important;

Comment: Show some code otherwise nobody can help you as we don't know what you did.

Comment: Added. It's word-wrap: break-word !important;

Comment: @CalifLRev you MUST use the non-breakable space `&nbsp;` (`"\xa0"` in js) in non-splittable text

Answer (score 2):

Use white-space property and set that property to nowrap

`<p style="white-space: nowrap;">John Smith</p>`

This tells the browser to display the name as a single line of text and prevent it from breaking across multiple lines. If you have a longer name or a narrower container element, you may need to adjust the white-space property or the font size to ensure that the name fits on a single line.